# Is there a punishment for a woman who enters marriage and hides her prior sexual experience from the husband?

Tags: zina

Is there such a punishment in Shariah, is it implemented in practice and, if yes, in which countries?

Comment: As written, this question shows absolutely no research effort.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to this:

1. Is there punishment for previous acts of adultery? Yes, if they are not repented in sincerity as highlighted by @yawar.
2. There is no sin/punishment/etc for you not telling your husband. Islam only dictates that husband and wife are two equal partners and mutual respect for one another; it does not define what exactly you may *tell your husband* of your previous life. If you have truly repented, then the matter is between you and Allah and not between you and your husband. You may chose to tell him at your discretion, but there is no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is punishment if you are referring to the tag for this question, but if you sincerely repent and never do the sin again ever after, then Allah is oft forgiving and merciful, and in that case no need to disclose your sin. You should seek forgiveness of Allah and ask him for guidance.

Allah Azawajjal says in sura Nur : The light (24)

*The first five verses are mentioned below*

> [This is] a surah which We have sent down and made [that within it]
>   obligatory and revealed therein verses of clear evidence that you
>   might remember.
>
> The [unmarried] woman or [unmarried] man found guilty of sexual
>   intercourse - lash each one of them with a hundred lashes, and do not
>   be taken by pity for them in the religion of Allah , if you should
>   believe in Allah and the Last Day. And let a group of the believers
>   witness their punishment.
>
> The fornicator does not marry except a [female] fornicator or
>   polytheist, and none marries her except a fornicator or a polytheist,
>   and that has been made unlawful to the believers.
>
> And those who accuse chaste women and then do not produce four
>   witnesses - lash them with eighty lashes and do not accept from them
>   testimony ever after. And those are the defiantly disobedient,
>
> **Except for those who repent thereafter and reform, for indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.**

The laws of sharia regarding this sin are implemented almost in all middle-east and malaysia and indonesia.